# Open image with create process and ms paint

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, paint, createprocess

Hi i have task to open image with  mspaint (microsoft paint) and do that with **create process** (windows.h)

how can i do that?
i try :

```
STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    std::string p = pic.getPath();
    if (CreateProcessA(LPCSTR(p),"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
```

and another thing , i need to close it with control c and make sure that **my exe doesn't close**
how can i do that also?

thanks

Comment: (0) What happened when you tried the above code. (1) MSPaint isn't closed with Ctrl-C. Presumably, the answer to that part is "you can't"

Comment: i need to put the Ctrl-C in handler to kill the program who open the picture but i dont know how to do that

Comment: and for (0) the mspaintopen but without the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameters to `CreateProcessA()` are wrong.

For one thing, you can't typecast a `std::string` to an `LPCSTR` (aka `const char*`) the way you are doing.

And second, even if that compiled (which it shouldn't), you have the first 2 parameters backwards. You are passing the picture file path in the `lpApplicationName` parameter, and the `mspaint` path in the `lpCommandLine` parameter. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) states:

> If both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpApplicationName` specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpCommandLine` specifies the command line. The new process can use `GetCommandLine` to retrieve the entire command line. Console processes written in C can use the `argc` and `argv` arguments to parse the command line. Because `argv[0]` is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.

In other words, you are trying to execute the picture file as an application, which it is not. You need to execute `mspaint` instead, passing it the picture file as a command-line argument.  In this case, it would be best to just use `lpCommandLine` by itself and ignore the `lpApplicationName`:

> The `lpApplicationName` parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the `lpCommandLine` string.

Try this instead:

```cpp
STARTUPINFOA info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
std::string p = pic.getPath();
std::string cmd = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe \"" + p + "\"";
if (CreateProcessA(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(cmd.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

As for closing the MSPaint process, you can't use <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> for that.  Instead, find the `HWND` that belongs to the MSPaint window, and then send it a `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_QUIT` message.  `CreateProcess()` tells you the main thread ID of the spawned process, you can use `EnumThreadWindows()` to find all of the `HWND`s that belong to that thread. And then use `SendMessage()` to send messages to them.